# Help Me Solve A Null Pointer

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

I am trying to refactor some code. Right now I have a trigger calling lots of methods. And I would like to to have it call on master method. Right now  I am getting a null pointer exception. And I don't understand why. I feel like I did all the right things to make  I am not referencing an empty collection. 
I am not even getting the issue seems to be in the healthCheckController method.

Any help would be great.

> Error: "Relationship_Owner_Trigger_Handler: execution of
>   BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object
>   Class.RelationshipOwner_Health_Checks.healthCheckController: line 20,
>   column 1 Trigger.Relationship_Owner_Trigger_Handler: line 18, column
>   1"

**The Trigger**

```
trigger Relationship_Owner_Trigger_Handler on relationship_owner__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {



if (Trigger.isBefore) {
if (Trigger.isInsert) {
// Call class logic here!
//EmailCountHandler.uniqueRelationshipOwnerEmails(Trigger.new);
}
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    //UniquePardotEmailCountHandler.countUniqueRelationshipOwnerEmails(Trigger.new);

RelationshipOwner_Health_Checks.healthCheckController(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new);//*****Line 18 Is here*****
```

**And the Class**

```
public with sharing class RelationshipOwner_Health_Checks {

  //method calls other methods to run scoring
    public static void healthCheckController(Map<Id, relationship_owner__c> oldMap, List<relationship_owner__c> newList){
    //methods for total unsubscribes

   List<relationship_owner__c> unsubscribeUpdate;
    for(relationship_owner__c owner : newList){
        relationship_owner__c oldOwner = oldMap.get(owner.Id);

        if (owner.Total_Unsubscribes_DLRS__c != oldOwner.Total_Unsubscribes_DLRS__c
                && owner.Total_Unsubscribes_DLRS__c != null) {
            unsubscribeUpdate.add(owner);
            System.debug('Total unsubsribes found and passed to method = ' + unsubscribeUpdate.size());                        
        }
    }
    if(!unsubscribeUpdate.isEmpty()){
        updateOwnerUnsubscribeRate(unsubscribeUpdate);            
    }//**** Line 20 is here***************
    //final score
    //final grade
}

public static void updateOwnerUnsubscribeRate(List<relationship_owner__c> relationshipOwnersList){
    for(relationship_owner__c owner : relationshipOwnersList){
        owner.Unsubscribe_Rate__c = owner.Total_Unsubscribes_DLRS__c / owner.Total_Influencers_DLRS__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Brooks, what line is the NPE thrown on?

Comment: Even though including your error helps, it is difficult to match a line number to a code sample on this site. Please track down which line is indicated and **[edit]** your post to make it clear and easy for us to identify as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<relationship_owner__c> unsubscribeUpdate;
```

`unsubscribeUpdate` is uninitialized. Every method call against that object will throw a `NullPointerException`.

As an aside, this code *looks* like it potentially could be replaced with a formula field referencing your DLRS lookups. I don't know that I see enough of the flow represented here to be sure of that.

Comment: I added the error in  above.  The formula exceeded the byte limits. It was referencing lookups that were referencing lookups. So I added it to Process Builder. But PB always has bulk issues. That was why I decided to refactor.

Comment: An embarrassing thing to miss for sure. I didn't think an error like that could get past the compiler?

Comment: There is relatively little static analysis-type error checking in the compiler. It's legal to declare, pass, and use uninitialized objects and primitives (both of which have the value `null`).